# How work this insert and update with if statement query in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IFNULL(post.id
,INSERT INTO post(pdate,body) VALUES (1,'a')
,UPDATE post set body='update',pdate=2
)
from post where body='a' and pdate=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc`
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT post.id from post where body='a' and pdate=1) THEN
UPDATE post set body='update',pdate=2;
ELSE
INSERT INTO post(pdate,body) VALUES (1,'a');
END IF;
END //
```

Comment: Thanks but ,I will generate this query in php without stored procedure

Comment: @Ali:- In that case simply remove the `CREATE PROCEDURE` and use it in your PHP code.

Comment: I know , but I want execute this query in one request , instead multiple queries

Comment: @Ali:- Then the straight answer to it is, **it is not possible**